# In the if block my for loop is not working hence 1,2,32 gets toasted and 3 doesn't

Tags: java, android

In the if block my for loop is not working hence 1,2,32 gets toasted and 3 doesn't. Getting the MaxaddressLineIndex is not proper hence I can't convert the latitude and longitude of the address to string.
https://www.journaldev.com/15676/android-geocoder-reverse-geocoding

```
 private void getAddressFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude)
        {        
                 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);    
        try
        {    
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);    
            printToast("1");   
            if (addresses.size() > 0)   
            {  
                  printToast("2");  
                Address fetchedAddress;  
                fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);  
                StringBuilder strAddress = new StringBuilder();  
                printToast("32");  
                for (int i = 0; i < fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)    
                  {    
                    printToast("3");  
                    strAddress.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(" ");  
                }  
                txtLocationAddress.setText(strAddress.toString());  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                txtLocationAddress.setText("Searching Current Address");  
            }  
        }  
        catch (IOException e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
            printToast("Could not get address..!");  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: The return of fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex() is 0, so the  code nevers loops

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i <= fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){    
    printToast("3");
    strAddress.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(" ");  
}
```

getMaxAddressLineIndex is returning 0.

Comment: This will cause IndexOfTheBoundsException

Comment: int getMaxAddressLineIndex ()

Returns the largest index currently in use to specify an address line. If no address lines are specified, -1 is returned.